# Problems using json recursive in treemap using D3PLUS

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, treemap, d3plus

I'm using the D3PlUS JS library (http://d3plus.org/) and I need to implement a treemap chart with a json recursive structure. I could just to do a first level treemap chart, but I couldn't do mack my code to be multilevel.

example.json

```
[
    {
        "id":"First cell",
        "value": 10,
        "child": 
        [ 
            {
                "id":"Child first cel",
                "value": 10,
                "child":[]
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "id":"Second cell",
        "value": 90,
        "child": 
        [ 
            {
                "id":"Child second cell 1",
                "value": 10,
                "child":[]
            },
            {
                "id":"Child second cell 2",
                "value": 20,
                "child":[]
            },{
                "id":"Child second cell 3",
                "value": 10,
                "child":[]
            }
        ]
    } 
]
```

---

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link href="http://d3plus.org/css/d3plus.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3plus.org/js/d3.geo.tile.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3plus.org/js/topojson.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3plus.org/js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>

<!-- create container element for visualization -->
<div id="viz"></div>

<script>

  // instantiate d3plus
  var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#viz")  // container DIV to hold the visualization
    .data("data/exemple.json")
    .type("tree_map")   // visualization type
    .id("id")         // key for which our data is unique on
    .size("value")      // sizing of blocks
    .draw()             // finally, draw the visualization!

</script>
```

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Two modifications were necessary:

- changing the data to what is expected by the chart, paying special attention to getting the IDs right (see [docs](http://d3plus.org/workshops/11_19_2013/tree_map/)). This was the trickiest part.
- nesting the ids in the config param, in accordance with the data: `.id(["id","cid"])`

Here is a complete working [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/wKlAwogM9E4BIcEsgGPz?p=preview).

**EDIT:** Per OP request, I added one more level to the treemap. It is important to keep the id hierarchy, so now the config param is: `.id(["id","cid","gid"])`. Also, make sure to remove the `value` field in the json file for all records that have children...otherwise, D3plus will consider that as part of the values to display with the children.

Comment: Hey @FernOfTheAndes, thks for answer me! But I'm trying to adding more  a level in your example, but I dont know what yet. Can help me about?

Comment: @TulioCruz Please see my edit to the plunk, which now has 3 levels. You should be able to extend this further if needed based on the instructions above.